# Breaking from repeat step using count of retreived vertices

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have a graph structure that looks something like the following:

```
user1 -> user2 -> user3 -> post
user1 -> user4 -> user5 -> post2
user1 -> user4 -> user6 -> post3
user1 -> user5 -> user7 -> post4
user1 -> user5 -> user6 -> post5
```

I would like to create a traversal which can search N edges deep from `user1` and then get posts on the user vertices at depth N. This would be usually be straight forward. But I have the following conditions:

- Be able to execute in a depth first search strategy
- Break from traversal when a given threshold for desired amount of posts is reached
- Ensure that for each `.repeat()` users vertices retrieved in `.out()` are random and not used in a previous `.repeat()` step

These conditions were made up by me with the hopes of ensuring that query time is acceptable even with a large number of user connections and post vertices.

Here is where I am testing with 2 degrees deep:

```
g.withSideEffect('Neptune#repeatMode', 'DFS')\
    .V(user1)\
    .repeat(__.out("connection").sample(1).out("connection").sample(1).out("post").limit(5).store("posts"))\
    .until(__.select("post").count().is_(50))\
    .values("name")\
    .toList()
```

This query never returns data as it only breaks when the number of posts on a user is `50`. But here the number of posts can only ever be 5 as the store is being re-written on each repeat?
So I think I need some kind of global state/store where vertices can be stored and then evaluated in `.until()`. Is this even possible? I saw that using a `sack()` might be a solution but I couldn't get my head around it.

Please can someone point me in the right direction to solving this problem. I might be trying to solve this using the wrong traversal techniques - but this was the closest I could come to something that seemed to make sense.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

After more hours of testing and re-reading: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-query-hints-repeatMode.html. I believe I now grasp how DFS operates in Neptune w/Gremlin Traversal and this have found a solution. But please take with a grain of salt if you are to use this. Verification from someone else that this operates how I expect would be nice.

I was under the impression that Neptune would evaluate the repeat traversals (in their totality) first and then evaluate the preceding steps. I believe this interpretation to be wrong after looking at the link above. It instead will evaluate each repeat/until + proceeding step(s) of the traversal until some condition is met such as `.limit()` - or the traversal is exhausted and all paths have been traversed.

With that in mind the following should work how I want:

```
g.withSideEffect('Neptune#repeatMode', 'DFS')\
    .V(user_vertex)\
    .repeat(__.out("connection").simplePath().order().by(Order.shuffle).dedup())\
    .until(__.loops().is_(P.eq(2)))\
    .local(__.out("post").sample(1))\
    .limit(50)\
    .values("name", "user")\
    .toList()
```

If my thinking is out of shape - please let me know with a comment. Thanks!